# ASP.Net web application - server side canceling Submit PostBackUrl if not(!) Page.IsValid

Tags: asp.net, validation-controls

I have a web application, and the submit uses the `PostBackUrl` to display data if the form is valid.

I need to use different (server side) validation groups, depending on what `radiobutton` is selected. That is, manually call

```
Page.Validate('ValidationGroupA').
```

The validation itself is working fine, in terms of `Page.IsValid` correctly assigned true or false.

However, if the page is not valid, the page redirects to the page specified by `PostBackUrl` on the submit button, where the page is found not to be valid, and the client redirected back with:

```
if (!PreviousPage.IsValid){Response.Redirect("DataEntryPage.aspx");})
```

However, by getting to here and back again, all form data is lost, and the relevant validation controls and summaries are not displayed.

Is there any equivalent of JavaScripts `evt.preventDefault()` or some other way, once it is detected validation has failed after a manual call to `Page.Validate` to post the form back with appropriate validation errors displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up removing the PostBackUrl directive, and using an onclick event for the submit button

```
protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (chartTypeRadio.Text != "bolus") { Page.Validate("age"); }
   if (Page.IsValid) { Server.Transfer("~/PatientSpecificDrugChart.aspx", true); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use ASP.Net Client Side Validation.**

*jQuery Code* (call this on onclick of submit button):

```
  $("#SubmitButtonID").click(function (e) {
      Page_ClientValidate('ValidationGroupA');
      if (!Page_IsValid)
      {
         e.preventDefault();
      }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am actually currently using client side javascript extensively similar to your suggestion. However, this validation needs to occur server side, as it needs to lookup a database. I could write some ajax to do the validation, but these validations are final fail-safes for for edge cases, and thus it does not seem worth it.